# Raspberry PI touchscreen mode

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I am building a Kiosk type system using a RaspPI with touchscreen. Basically a webpage (fullPageOS) with buttons.. My problem is the way the mouse/touchscreen behaves.. for example I have an onscreen keyboard (just a bunch of divs). However I have to hit each key twice, as the first touch moves the pointer to the button and the second does the mouse_down.
I dont know what to look for.. maybe an alternate driver or something. I need the mouse to be invisible and act like on a mobile phone..